# In linear model, if you add one more variable, then what happens to the constant?

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression, linear-model

I have a linear model

$$y=a+bX_1+cX_2+dX_3+eX_4+m,$$

where the expected value of $m$ given $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ is zero.

If you add one more variable $X_5$ to this model, is the constant $a$ expected to be higher than in the original model?

Also, is there a difference in Goodness of Fit ($R^2$)?

I don't understand the first part, but in the second part, since goodness of fit is not affected by covariates, therefore there is no change in goodness of fit.

Can anyone help me with the first one?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be expressed sufficiently clearly to be sure of precisely what you want to know.

Comment: Of course there is a difference in goodness of fit when you include $X_5$: it will go up.